# What is the right way to init a Riverpod notifier with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have these classes for my model:

```
@freezed
class Generator with _$Generator {

  factory Generator({
    required int id,
    required double cost,
  }) = _Generator;

  factory Generator.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)  => _$GeneratorFromJson(json);
}


@riverpod
class GeneratorsNotifier extends _$GeneratorsNotifier {

  @override
  List<Generator> build() {
    return [
      for (final g in [
        {
          'id': 0,
          'cost': 2.63,
        },
        {
          'id': 1,
          'cost': 20.63,
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'cost': 139.63,
        },
        {
          'id': 3,
          'cost': 953.63,
          
        },
        {
          'id': 4,
          'cost': 5653.63,
        },
      ]) Generator.fromJson(g)
    ];
  }

  void addGenerator(Map<String, Object?> json) {
    state = [...state, Generator.fromJson(json)];
  }

  void changePrice(int id) {
    state = [
      for (final generator in state)
        if (generator.id == id)
          _createUpdatedGenerator(generator)
        else
          generator,
    ];
  }

  Generator _createUpdatedGenerator(Generator generator) {
    double newPrice = ...some logic here...
    Generator updatedGenerator = generator.copyWith(
        price: newPrice,
    );
    return updatedGenerator;
  }

}
```

The price for one single item is changed from another notifier:

```
@riverpod
class GameStatusNotifier extends _$GameStatusNotifier {

  @override
  GameStatus build() {
    return GameStatus(
      // some params
    );
  }

  void changePrice(int id) {
    state = ...some logic here that change the status...
    // now try to update the status of GeneratorsNotifier
    ref.read(generatorsNotifierProvider.notifier).changePrice(id);
  }
}
```

The flow is working as expected but every time the `build()` method of `GeneratorsNotifier` is called, the state gets reset to the initial values. That does not happen for example for the `build()` in `GameStatusNotifier` (and for another example in documentation). How can I fix `GeneratorsNotifier` to not reset the status after `build()` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, generated providers are autodispose.  Your provider is resetting when nobody watches it.  To fix that, review the keepAlive options.

Answer (score 0):

keepalive or watch the provider in your widget build where you want to keep.